# are some prepositions (e.g. “concerning”) actually just irregular passive forms of verbs (e.g. “to concern” )

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, prepositions

Trying to understand the roles prepositions play. It seems to me that as well as the obvious positional information they express (in, on, under etc) they also serve as passive forms of some verbs.

- active voice: Dave is killing
- passive: Dave is killed
- Active voice: Dave is concerned
- passive voice: Dave is being
  concerned

Instead of saying "Dave is being concerned" (passive verb), we say "concerning Dave" (preposition). Semantically, are these not the same thing? I imagine the difference is that, as a preposition, "concerning" is now subject to different word ordering rules when used in a sentence.

Is all this true or am I barking up the wrong tree? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd guess that "concerning Dave" is a shortening of something like "this is concerning Dave" or "something concerning Dave is..." but there is no passive there. Also note that "Dave is concerned" could mean something different to "This concerned Dave": in the former "concerned" means worried, while the latter might mean was related to.

Comment: There are very different usages in this area. 'Dave was concerned about the possible findings' is very different from 'The wrong panel was concerned in the assessment.' The first is the adjective (= worried), the second is the transitive MWV 'concern[/involve] someone in something' [[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/concern+in)]. // 'The facts concerning Dave' correspond more closely to 'the facts about/relating to Dave'.

Comment: @Stuart F.  Thanks for your response! If it means "this is concerning Dave", i.e. concerning (preposition) = "this is concerning" (active verb).  Does that means the preposition is just a collapsed form of the verb where you don't have to specify the "this is" part as it becomes implicit? So I may have been incorrect about the passive aspect- but correct in the sense that the preposition is semantically just a verb form?

Comment: Do unexplained noises concern you? If so, they're concerning.